# File upload with Karate Robot is not working in Bamboo/Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, karate, bamboo

I have a scenario where I need to upload a file in my test application, am currently using the below code to upload

```
  * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: false}
   * click("#uploadbtn")
   * robot { window: '^Open', highlight: true }
   * robot.input(filepath + Key.ENTER)
```

When am running this code in Bamboo/Jenkins am getting the below error

- robot { window: '^Open', highlight: true }
  robot init failed: failed to find window: ^Open

Kindly help me handling this file upload scenario in the CI/CD setup, the same code in my local works good.

Comment: robot is not recommended. use chrome or the other options explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#driverinputfile